# Apache log says "404" but my ErrorDocument is ignored and browser says "The requested URL ... has moved"

Tags: apache-2.4, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I'm trying to setup some customer error pages on our Apache servers, which seemed straightforward.   The 503 is working right, but the 404 is not.   They're setup the same:

```
<LocationMatch "/my/uri">
    ErrorDocument 503 /errorCustom.html
    ErrorDocument 404 /errorCustom.html
</LocationMatch>
```

But when I hit a bad URL in the site, the Apache log clearly says it triggered a 404 as expected:

```
123.123.123.123 [22/Nov/2021:10:15:17 -0500] "GET /my/uri/%2f%20%20has%20moved.%20Please%20go%20to%20www.garbage.com/.%20The%20requested%20URL HTTP/1.1" 404 273 201 my-masked.hostname.com (-) "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36"
```

But the browser doesn't display the custom error html page ... browser just tells me this ...

> Not Found
> The requested URL /my/uri// has moved.
> Please go to [www.garbage.com/](http://www.garbage.com/).
> The requested URL was not found on this server

---

So I think the "moved" part is important in the message, but I can't figure out how to correct it and make the 404 ErrorDocument get triggered.   What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: There may be other configuration settings in effect that take precedence. Check for example  the httpd.conf,  any included virtualhost directives  and/or for the presence of a .htaccess file

Comment: The log entry looks strange. Did you really enter `http://my-masked.hostname.com/my/uri/%2f%20%20has%20moved.%20Please%20go%20to%20www.garbage.com/.%20The%20requested%20URL` as URL in your browser?